# Control characters (\001-\x01 and \002-\x02) not treated correctly by Gnome-Terminal

Tags: bash, centos, terminal

Re-do of the same question, hopefully in a new format and in the correct platform.

I have a machine (let's nickname it *Eddy*) with centos 7 and bash 4.2 on it, **gnome-terminal** 3.28.2, that prints broken characters whenever it finds one of the aforementioned control characters. Command typed:

`echo -e "\x01\e[0;34mGoodDay\x01\e[0m\x02"`

Expected output:

[image]

This output was printed on another machine, on Konsole 2.10.5 connected to Eddy through ssh.

Obtained output (on *Eddy*):

[image]

As you can see the machine is the same, but the output is clearly not.

The characters I tried are: `\x01 \x02` (Hex), `\001 \002` (Oct) and `\[ \]`, but in the last case the square brackets are printed as is, not interpreted:

[image]

I checked for LANG variables etcetera, bit everything seems to indicate that Eddy itself has the most recent versions of those files/standards.

I added these characters (as per this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19501528/21389760 ) so the prompt (in case i use it in a `read -p` command) is correctly wrapped and any non-printing characters do not take any space on the screen.
Somehow though the problem exists only on *Eddy*, and i haven't found any solution online.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior with GNOME Terminal version 3.48 and VTE version 0.73. For me, GNOME Terminal / VTE don't print anything when receiving a `\x01` or `\x02`. What are your version numbers (it's VTE's version that really matters -- try e.g. `echo $VTE_VERSION`) on Eddy? Anyway, the _real_ answer to your overall problem is already provided by @user1686: these chars are internal to the readline library and aren't supposed to make it to the terminal, so the said GNOME Terminal bug, even if present, should be irrelevant to you.

Comment: I've just noticed you mentioned your gnome-terminal is version  3.28, which is typically paired with vte 0.52. vte version 0.54 introduced a brand new parser, so it's highly likely that 0.54 fixed the behavior of `\x01` and `\x02`. (But again, this should be irrelevant to you, the way readline internally uses these bytes should never be visible to the terminal emulator. If these bytes end up being sent to the terminal then you haven't configured your readline prompt correctly.)

Comment: @egmont So yeah i've tried echo $VTE_VERSION on _Eddy_ and it prints 5204. I tried it on the machine with konsole, where the *echo* works and is empty, for some reason.
I should add that i have updated vte on _Eddy_ to 0.28, before echoing VTE_VERSION.

Comment: 5204 is version 0.52.4, i.e. before the parser rewrite. konsole isn't based on vte, or if you ssh then the value might not be forwarded, so no surprise if it isn't set there. 0.28 is an ancient incompatible version, I highly hope you're not using that. It's probably installed in parallel to a newer version, bearing a different package name. Look for a package named vte3 or vte2.91 or alike, version being anywhere from 0.52 to 0.72-ish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These control characters are not meant to be printed to the terminal at all – they're meant to be consumed by the Readline library *before* it displays the prompt, as their purpose is to help Readline's width calculations (precisely because it has to determine the width of your prompt *without* any help from the terminal<sup>1</sup>).

So they are only useful if you use `read` together with the `-e` ("use Readline") option, but you have to omit them from the prompt otherwise.

What you're seeing is more or less normal differences in behavior between Konsole and GNOME Terminal (or specifically libVTE) when printing "unprintable" characters that otherwise have no defined effect to a terminal, and it is not just GNOME Terminal that makes control characters visible – other terminals may do so as well.

The same applies to the `\[` `\]` sequences – they are there *specifically* for Bash for use in PS1 or PS2 (which really just converts them to `\x01` and `\x02` before giving the prompt string to the Readline library) and make no sense in any other context.

<sup>1</sup> (The terminal doesn't need such help as it *is* the renderer and already understands what the wrapped `\e[...` sequences do and how they affect the layout.)

Comment: My fault for not being clear, but echo is just a command i used to explain my problem, i use the color codes wrapped in \x01 and \x02 for my scripts (they contain both **echoes** and **read -e** so i thought to write them down all wrapped as parameters).

Comment: The answer is still the same. If you're using `read -e` then it's `read -e` that needs to consume and filter out \x01 \x02 – not the terminal.

Comment: I tried with read -e and it effectively works, i'll have to modify my scripts accordingly but now they will work as intended. Thanks!